# All roots of $z^4=8\left(1-i\cdot\sqrt{3}\right)$

Tags: complex-numbers

I was given the task to find all 4 $z_k$ so that

## $$z =\sqrt[4]{w}$$

$$w =8\cdot\left(1-i\cdot\sqrt{3}\right) = 8-8i\cdot\sqrt3 $$
$$Arg(w) = arctan(\frac{-8\cdot\sqrt{3}}{8}) = arctan(-\sqrt{3})$$

By using the formula by De Moivre I get:
$$\tag{k = 0,1,2,3}z_k=\sqrt[4]{\left|w\right|}\cdot e^{i\left(\frac{\left(Arg\left(w\right)+2k\pi\right)}{4}\right)}$$ 
$$\left|w\right|=16$$

This one is actually easy to solve (example for k = 0)
$$z_0=2\cdot e^{i\left(\frac{Arg\left(w\right)}{4}\right)}$$
$$z_0=2\cdot\left(\cos\left(\frac{\arctan\left(-\sqrt{3}\right)}{4}\right)+i\cdot\sin\left(\frac{\arctan\left(-\sqrt{3}\right)}{4}\right)\right)$$
$$z_0=1,93185 - 0,517638\cdot i$$

The given solution is equal but looks something like this:
$$z_0 = \frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}\right)+\frac{1}{2}i\left(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{6}\right)$$

**My question is how did they manage to get a solution that includes roots and so on?**

Comment: Use $\,\arctan(-\sqrt{3})=-60^\circ$.

Comment: Oh yeah I could do that. I did not know that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$z^4 = 16 e^{-\frac {\pi}{3}i}\\
z = 2 e^{-\frac {\pi}{12}i}\\
2(\cos -\frac {\pi}{12} + i\sin  -\frac {\pi}{12})\\
2(\cos (\frac {\pi}{4} - \frac {\pi}{3}) + i\sin (\frac {\pi}{4} - \frac {\pi}{3}))\\
z = 2(\frac {\sqrt {6} + \sqrt {2}}{4} + i\frac {-\sqrt {6} + \sqrt {2}}{4})$

This is one root.

The other roots are the roots of

$z^4 = 1\\
z = 1,i,-1, -i$

Times the root found above.

Comment: The last part makes totally sense to me but how did you jump from term 2 to term 3? How did you divide all that by 4? I mean you prob used e^xi = cos(x) + i * sin(x) but how?

Comment: @FinnEggers I published too soon.  Is this more clear?

Comment: Not really to be honest. I mean how do you know that cos(pi / 4 - pi /3) = sqrt(6) + sqrt(2) over 4?

Comment: haven't you learned angle addition identities?  $\cos (a-b) = \cos a \cos b + \sin a\sin b$?

Comment: Ufff. Yeah meabe. I actually just looked that up and found it in the script but I am pretty sure my prof skipped it in class. But that make sense :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

HINT: it is $$z^4-8(1-i\sqrt{3})=(z^2-2\sqrt{3}+2i)(z^2+2\sqrt{3}-2i)$$

Comment: What is? Shouldn't there be an "=" ?

Comment: it is just corrected

Comment: I see, but how exactly does that help me?

Comment: solve the factors for $z$